# Regex - Match column name in a CSV string

Tags: python, regex, csv

Complete Regex newbie here, so pardon me if this is a silly question. I have a row in a CSV file of the form:

`test_id|column1|column10|column11|column101|`

and I need to be able to match the first occurrence of one of the following in Python and get its position in the string:

```
column1|, |column1| or |column1
```

I tried using `[\|]?column1[\|]?`on https://regexr.com/ to see how it goes, but it matches everything with a column1 in it. How do I go about it?

Edit: I completely agree with the comments that there's no need for a Regex with Python here. However, if I just wanted to match the pattern using regex, how would I go about it?

Comment: Can't you use "column1 followed by a single non-alphabetic character"?

Comment: You can just try `line.split('|').index('column1')`. This will give you the position of 'column1' in your columns list or raise `ValueError` if nothing would be found.

Comment: why would you use regex for this??

Comment: Silly me, should have just given it more thought! What if I needed to this in Regex BTW?

Comment: you don't need to do anything in regex, as a general way. certainly you *shouldn't* use regex for this.

Comment: Beginning of string or pipe then `column1` then pipe or newline. Or just open the file using a csv parser with pipe delimited and check if any item in row equals your search string.

Comment: I agree, there's no need for regex if I'm using Python. However, I'm curious, how would I match the pattern using Regex?

Comment: When I paste your regex into the site you mentioned, I only match `|column1|`

Comment: I just told you how.  Use a reference to turn my first sentence into a regex.

Comment: `import re; p = re.compile(r'column1'); m = p.search(line); m.start(); m.group(0)`

Comment: Thank you all. The site had the global flag /g applied, which matched everything with 'column1' in it. Removed it and it worked!

Comment: @theguyoverthere no, it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying that you store the row as a string, so:

```
str1 = "test_id|column1|column10|column11|column101|"
```

Then you can just use the `index()` method to find the index of each occurrence you are looking for.

```
strs = ["column1|", "|column1|", "|column1"]

for s in strs:
    print(str1.index(s))
```

Obviously you will have to do error checking, but this will return the index.

This prints:

```
8
7
7
```